# Efficient way of finding Simple Sequence repeats in Java

Tags: java, regex, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have to find Simple sequence repeats and have to store each unique repeat along with their position. I have already written a perl code to do that(which does have tons of if and for for finding repeats till pentamers). My question is, is there some simpler way to do this in java, like some regex or something which searches the string and returns me the count of consecutive repeats and positions, something which doesn't involves many control statements and iterations.

Update: A simple sequence repeat(SSR) is simply a uninterrupted repeated string of characters, starting from dimer(i.e two different characters repeating together.). It is like a word being repeated in a sentence continuously without break. In case of DNA, it would look like

```
AATTAAAATTTTAAAAAAAAGGGCCCTTTAA[ATATATATATATAT]AAGGGATTTAAGGAATTAAGA[TGATGATGATGATGA]TGGTAG
```

Here AT and TGA are simple sequence repeats, AT is a dimer, and TGA is a trimer.
What I have to find is the start position of Sequence repeat,how many times it is being repeated(i.e. the length) and which sequence it is(i.e AT is for example starting at position 6, it is being repeated 10 times, TGA is starting at position 25 and so on)

My perl code :(And it is kind of buggy)

```
my $i=0;
my $j=0;
my $dna;
my $m2=0;
my $m4=0;
my $m3=0;
my $m5=0;
my $temp1;
my $temp2;
my $min;

print "Please enter DNA sequence : ";
$dna=<>;
my $firstdi;
my $seconddi;
my $thirddi;
my $fourthdi;
my $fifthtet;
my $firsttet;
my $secondtet;
my $thirdtet;
my $fourthtet;
my $fifthtet;
my $firsttri;
my $secondtri;
my $thirdtri;
my $fourttri;
my $fifthtri;
my $firstpent;
my $secondpent;
my $thirdpent;
my $fourtpent;
my $fifthpent;
print "\n";
print "Please enter the length to search for : ";
$motif=<>;
print "\n";
print "Please enter the minimum number of motif repeats : " ;
$min=<>;
chomp($dna);
chomp($motif);
chomp($min);
my @output;
my @codearr = split //, $dna;
print "\n";print @codearr;print "\n";
my $arrsize=@codearr;
print "\nSize : ";
print "\n";print $arrsize; print "\n";
print "Output : ";
my $total=0;


if($motif==2)
{
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-2);$i=$i+$motif)
{
    if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
  $temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1]);
  $temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+2],$codearr[$i+3]);
   if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
 if($m2==0)
 {
 $ms1=$i;
 }
 $total++;
 $m2++;
 }
}
}
}



if($motif==3)
{
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-2);$i=$i+$motif)
{if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
  $temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1]);
  $temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+2],$codearr[$i+3]);
   if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m2==0)
 {
 $ms1=$i;
 }
 $m2++;
  $total++;
 }
}
}

for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-3);$i=$i+$motif)
{if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
$temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1],$codearr[$i+2]);
$temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+3],$codearr[$i+4],$codearr[$i+5]);
 if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m3==0)
 {
 $ms3=$i;
 }
 $m3++;
  $total++;
 }
}
}
}



if($motif==4)
{
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-2);$i=$i+$motif)
{
    if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
  $temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1]);
  $temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+2],$codearr[$i+3]);
   if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m2==0)
 {
 $ms1=$i;
 }
 $m2++;
  $total++;
 }
}
}
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-3);$i=$i+$motif)
{
    if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
$temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1],$codearr[$i+2]);
$temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+3],$codearr[$i+4],$codearr[$i+5]);
 if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m3==0)
 {
 $ms3=$i;
 }
 $m3++;
  $total++;
 }
}
}
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-4);$i=$i+$motif)
{
    if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
$temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1],$codearr[$i+2],$codearr[$i+3]);
$temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+4],$codearr[$i+5],$codearr[$i+6],$codearr[$i+7]);
 if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m4==0)
 {
 $ms4=$i;
 }
 $m4++;
  $total++;
 }
}
}
}



if($motif==5)
{
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-2);$i=$i+$motif)
{if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
  $temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1]);
  $temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+2],$codearr[$i+3]);
   if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m2==0)
 {
 $ms1=$i;
 }
  $total++;
 $m2++;
 }
}  }
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-3);$i=$i+$motif)
{
    if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
$temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1],$codearr[$i+2]);
$temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+3],$codearr[$i+4],$codearr[$i+5]);
 if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m3==0)
 {
 $ms3=$i;
 }
  $total++;
 $m3++;
 }
}
}
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-4);$i=$i+$motif)
{
    if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
$temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1],$codearr[$i+2],$codearr[$i+3]);
$temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+4],$codearr[$i+5],$codearr[$i+6],$codearr[$i+7]);
 if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m4==0)
 {
 $ms4=$i;
 }
  $total++;
 $m4++;
 }
}
}
for($i=0;$i<($arrsize-5);$i=$i+$motif)
{if($codearr[$i] ne $codearr[$i+1])
    {
 $temp1 = join( "",$codearr[$i],$codearr[$i+1],$codearr[$i+2],$codearr[$i+3],$codearr[$i+4]);
 $temp2 = join( "",$codearr[$i+5],$codearr[$i+6],$codearr[$i+7],$codearr[$i+8],$codearr[$i+9]);
 if($temp1 eq $temp2)
 {
  if($m5==0)
 {
 $ms5=$i;
 }
  $total++;
 $m5++;
 }
}
}
}


if($motif==2)
{
  if($min<$total)
  {
print"Number of Dimer repeats : ";
    print $m2;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms1;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
}
else
  {
  print "No or less than minimum SSRs found";}
}

if($motif==3)
{
  if($min<$total)
  {
print"Number of Dimer repeats : ";
    print $m2;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms1;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
print"Number of Trimer repeats : ";
    print $m3;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms3;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
}
else
  {
  print "No or less than minimum SSRs found";}
}

if($motif==4)
{
  if($min<$total)
  {
print"Number of Dimer repeats : ";
    print $m2;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms1;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
print"Number of Trimer repeats : ";
    print $m3;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms3;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
print"Number of Tetramer repeats : ";
    print $m4;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms4;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
}
else
  {
  print "No or less than minimum SSRs found";}
}


if($motif==5)
{
  if($min<$total)
    {
print"Number of Dimer repeats : ";
    print $m2;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms1;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
print"Number of Trimer repeats : ";
    print $m3;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms3;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
print"Number of Tetramer repeats : ";
    print $m4;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms4;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
print"Number of Pentamer repeats : ";
    print $m5;
    print"\n";
    print"First position : ";
    print $ms5;
    print "\n";
    print "Sequence Lenght : ";
    print $arrsize;
    print "\n";
  }
  else
  {
  print "No or less than minimum SSRs found";}
}
```

Comment: Your perl code has way too much repetition. Also, could you clarify what you mean by `store each unique repeat along with their position`? (Maybe with a test case of **input** and **expected output**)

Comment: I know, well I was just trying, I could have gone with subroutines, but then again, I still don't have a clear logic in my mind.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: The problem is to find Simple Sequence repeats, for example, if I enter JHGJGGGIGIATATATATATAJHFJHHUJ, here AT will be considered a sequence repeat, more specifically a dimer. Oh, and there is always a threshold value, after which we can consider it to be a simple sequence repeat.

Comment: Does it have to occur contiguously? Regular expressions seem like the tool for this. I don't understand what you mean by threshold value. You can update your question with these details. The perl code isn't particularly helpful

Comment: @DarkCthulhu, yup it does need to be uninterrupted. But then again, a sequence can have multiple SSRs which are same, like *code*AT SSR*code*Some other SSR**code*AT SSR again*

Comment: Update your question with the details and a test case which covers the above.

Comment: Updated with details of SSR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like regexes should help you get started This applies to "**dimers**" you stated in your question and can be extended to find longer sequences.

```
String s = "AATTAAAATTTTAAAAAAAAGGGCCCTTTAAATATATATATATATAAGGGATTTAAGGAATTAAGATGATGATGATGATGATGGTAG";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([ATGC][ATGC])\\1+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
}
```

This gives an output:

```
Start index: 4 End index: 8 Found: AAAA
Start index: 8 End index: 12 Found: TTTT
Start index: 12 End index: 20 Found: AAAAAAAA
Start index: 31 End index: 45 Found: ATATATATATATAT
```

A **lexing library** might actually help you as you can build state machines out of these regexes which help identify more complex patterns. Take a look at [JLex](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/).

---

**Edit:** 
You said AA didn't count as a pattern, and that they had to be different characters.
You can try [**this regex**](http://ideone.com/UlTdqc) instead:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:([ATGC])(?!\\1)([ATGC])\\1\\2)+");
```

This has a lookahead assertion that ensures it isn't matching the same character.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a small problem in it. AA is not a sequence repeat, a dimer here means it can be AT or TA or anything, not repeating in it by itself, like it cannot be AA or TT. Although, I will try to rectify that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Siddharth That can be fixed with a negative look-ahead assertion. I'll update the regex in a while.

Comment: Thanks again, I am looking at JLex, it might help me in future projects where I might need to find biologically relevant patterns using precompiled databases.

Comment: Can I implement the same assertion for tetramers and so on ? Like AATAATAAT and as such.

Comment: @Siddharth You can, but it'll get progressively longer and harder to understand the regexes. A lexer on the other hand could handle such a sequence better I think, as it can construct more complex state machines out of several regular expressions.

Comment: I will try to implement JLex in my problem, although I don't know how much successful I am going to be, but still worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

This looks so much like LZ. Take a look, it might help you:

A high level view of the encoding algorithm is shown here:

Initialize the dictionary to contain all strings of length one.
Find the longest string W in the dictionary that matches the current input.
Emit the dictionary index for W to output and remove W from the input.
Add W followed by the next symbol in the input to the dictionary.
Go to Step 2.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch

You could also use a modified Trie, where the word indication would also store the number of repeats.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: I am kind of confused, should I populate the dictionary with all the possible combinations ? Let me rewrite the algorithm with my perspective. 1)Seed it with all the possible combinations of nucleotides/characters from a set.2)Find the longest "word" matching a substring from input sequence.3)Remove that substring and increase the counter.4)Continue the iteration until nothing is left from original input. How can this approach be better than using regex ?

Comment: Just the input string of length 1 used in the input file. In your case, A, T, G, C

Comment: Then the longest string can be (for example)AAAAAAA or so, whereas I need to find patterns which are continues, but different within themselves, like ATATATA

Comment: LZ works for both sequences of the same letter and repetitions of sequences. Take a look at the example provided in the wiki. TOBEORNOTTOBEORTOBEORNOT#

Comment: I am getting it now. Although I have time restrains, I will try to study LZ and implement it according to my problem. Thank you!(Although I still don't get how it can be better than using Jlex or regex)

Comment: I love regex, but for this particular case I think it would be a very brittle solution. I have another idea of what you could do. I will modify my first post.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand that regex will be not an efficient solution for finding large repeating sequences(hexamers and above), and will increase complexity.